# Vue js update array

Tags: vue.js

```
data: {
  addItemArray: [],
}
```

I have initialize one array inside data and then inside methods i am added some code:

```
var self = this;
{
  self.cacheDom.$submitItem.click(function () {
    self.addItemArray.push({
    ‘id’: $(’#accountSearch’).data(‘id’).trim(),
    ‘name’: $(’#accountSearch’).val().trim(),
    ‘type’: $(’#accountDropdown option:selected’ ).text().trim()
    });
    $(’.addItemMenu’).hide();
  });
}
```

i pushing the data into addItemArray. Then another one click function inside methods that time i need the addItemArray items. But i getting always a empty array.

Thanks

Comment: What is `self`? should it be: `self.data.addItemArray.push({ ... })`?

Comment: var self = this;

Comment: Click() in your javascript doesn't look very vue-like to me.. Are you sure you are doing your event handling right? The click attribute should come from the html not javascript..and please stay away from jquery unless you are using 3rd party tools

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: Thanks Darren Sweeney, It's right...